# Probability in infinite coin toss

Tags: probability, self-study, binomial-distribution

Let $X_n$ denotes the random outcome of the $n^{th}$ coin toss. On each toss a coin shows a head with probability $p$ and a tail with probability $1-p$, where $0\lt p \lt 1.$ That is
\begin{equation}
X_n = \begin{cases}
\text{H} & \text{with probability } p\\
\text{T} & \text{with probability } 1-p
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Assuming independence of individual outcomes $X_n$, show that $\mathbb{P}[X_n = \text{H} \quad \text{i.o.}] = 1$ and $\mathbb{P}[X_n=\text{T}\quad \text{i.o.}] = 1$ (i.o. means [infinitely often](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512810/definition-about-infinitely-often)).

**Comment:** it looks like it has something to do with Kolmogorov's 0-1 law, but I  am not able to exploit it to answer the question.

Comment: I've edited the question. Hopefully, it is clear now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply [2nd Borel-Cantelli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma) lemma and you will get the result.

You are right, here the *limsup* is a *tail* *event* and with Kolmogorov $0-1$ law you can say that it has either probability $1$ or $0$. However, applying $2nd$ Borel-Cantelli lemma you obtain that the probability is $1$ as the intuition suggested.

Comment: (+1) for remembering this lemma :)

Comment: @ Aksaka I'll never forget Borel–Cantelli lemma - I use it infinitely often.

Comment: This problem is the direct application of the lemma you stated. I was not aware of it. It would help in proving stuff involving probabilities of sequences of infinite lengths. Thanks a lot for the help